# ¿Como convertir una suma en string a float en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hola tengo el siguiente problema, en una variable tengo un string el cual es una operación numérica y necesito realizar dicha operación e imprimirla, pero heb estado buscando formas de transformar esta cadena a un int o float y aun no puedo convertirlo

```
ok1='2+2**2' #String
ok2= 0.0
ok3 = float (ok1)
for i in range(len(ok1)):
    print ok1[i]
    ok2=float(ok1[i])
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar **[`eval()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)** para determinar el valor de la operación representada en la cadena `ok1`.

Por ejemplo:

```
ok1='2+2**2' #String
ok3 = eval (ok1) #imprimirá el resultado, que es 6.
print(ok3)
```